# Git checkout não altera arquivos/pastas locais

Tags: git, github

Estou começando a me introduzir no GIT. E me surgiu um problema.

Aparentemente, o checkout não estava alterando os arquivos locais.

Deixe-me explicar melhor:

O meu fluxo é simples, clone, altera código, commit, push/pull, branch, checkout e alguns merges.

Sendo assim, eu fiz uma Branch nova para arrumar a estrutura de pastas do projeto.

Removi algumas, movi outras, criei novas pastas, etc. Ajustei tudo para que o projeto funcionasse.

Quando fiz o git status, recebi uma lista gigante com pastas/arquivos excluídos ou criados. Fui ver uma maneira mais fácil de fazer o git rm e o add. Então com o git add --help, decidi que o add --all era uma boa solução para mim.

Fiz o commit e o push, depois fui embora.

Pela manhã, minha equipe pegou a branch onde alterei o caminhos das pastas e começaram a trabalhar. Mais tarde, quando cheguei, resolvi fazer o pull para pegar as alterações do grupo.

Fui indo de branch a branch, para ver as alterações (checkout branch-name).

Percebi que todas as branchs estavam com erros, e comecei a pesquisar o porque. Logo cheguei a conclusão de que ao fazer checkout entre as branchs, minha nova estrutura continuava, e misturada com a estrutura antiga de pastas.

Tentei fazer reset HEAD --hard, mas não deu. Notei que independente do commit que estavas, os arquivos não eram alterados.

O jeito foi fazer um clone novo do projeto. Imagino que essa foi uma solução porca, mas depois de horas, foi a solução.

Gostaria de saber o que eu fiz de errado, para isso acontecer.

Alguém tem alguma idéia? O meu conceito sobre checkout esta equivocado?

Comment: Bom, explicando dessa forma não ajuda muito pra eu poder ajudar, mas vc chegou a verificar o seguinte:
1. As alterações realmente foram para o repositorio remoto ?
2. Voce está na branch correta ?
3. Tentou fazer um clone em um novo diretório, pra ver a estrutura ?
4. Quando deu pull, foi com sucesso ? vc viu os logs de alterações ?

Não são as soluções, porém vai te ajudar a verificar onde está seu erro.

Comment: @JosuéEduardo 
1) sim, as alterações foram para o repositório.
2) Sim, estou na branch correta.
3) Sim, no final, foi a solução que tive para voltar a trabalhar, fiz um clone em outro diretório.

4) Sim, não houve nenhum conflito no Pull.

5) Não sei verificar os logs... vou providenciar isto.

Answer (score 3):

Cutia,

Acredito que tem um erro aí no seu procedimento. Eu sigo um procedimento parecido com o seu e senti falta de uma coisa. Veja os passos que eu executo:

```
git pull
git checkout -b mytest
```

Aqui eu trabalho um monte, testo e estou satisfeito... Então:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff mytest
```

Eses passos acima é que acho que você precisava fazer.

```
git branch -d mytest
git commit -m "Explicação do que fiz"
git push
```

Pelo que percebi você não voltou para o seu master e faz o merge da branch que você criou.
O que vai importar para a sua equipe é o master (ou qualquer nome que vocês dão por aí).

Abraços,

Comment: na verdade estamos trabalhando em uma funcionalidade nova, então todos da equipe iriam usar essa branch, e não a master. Pois outra parte da equipe, iria dar continuidade em coisas de menos peso.

Comment: Faltou o procedimento no terminl git add *.*